# export column text data converting to numbers

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Using Access 2007 and importing into either Excel or SQL Server 2005. The data is changing as follows

so this in access:

```
id      TestNo     TestName
351418  190256     P. CARINII PNEUMONIA, STAIN                  
351419  190389     MATURATION INDEX  
351420  190520     CytoRich  
351421  192005     GYNECOLOGIC MONO-LAYER PAP  
351422  488296     GYN PAP SMEAR (ONE SLIDE)  
351423  489100     PAP (1 SL) H523 CAPSS  
351424  P81621     Cytopath Extended Study(PROF)
```

becomes this:

```
id      TestNo  TestName
351418  29  29    
351419  30  30    
351420  31  31    
351421  32  32    
351422  33  33    
351423  34  34    
351424  35  35
```

`TestNo` and `TestName` are `Text` with length of 25 in Access and `nvarchar(25)` in SQL Server.

Any ideas?

The defintion in SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[top1000testinfo](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TestNo] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [TestName] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [CPT] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [FFS] [money] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

this from a query that gets the top 1000 from the table. The table has about 100k rows. The same problem happens if I import the table with all the rows.  The problem happens to the TestNo, TestName,CPT and Type columns.  In the table ID is the pk. Also there are a Text(length 2) and a Text(length 5) that import correctly.

Also,  this table was created from table from an earlier Access version.  If I do the import with mdb file I get the same result.

Comment: I tried importing the above data to Excel and it went just fine. What did you do exactly to get the results above?

Comment: In the Access table design, are TestNo and TestName configured as lookup fields?

Comment: Kareem - how did you define the access table? Thanks

Comment: TestNo and TestName are not Lookup fields

Answer (score 0):

OK, Access is smart enough to get the foreign key values into those columns(testno,testname). How this happened I am not sure.